# Memoir Class - Modify `ell` chapter style

Tags: sectioning, memoir, chapters

In the memoir class, how can I modify the format for the `ell` chapter style. In the manual, the code is not listed (unlike the other styles).

[image: screendump]

Basically in the above, all I want to do is make the horizontal and vertical line a little thicker and of a different colour.

I have been through the source code of the memoir package, but cannot find where the code is for this particular chapter style.

Comment: In `memoir.cls` (version: `2016/05/16 v3.7f`), I have `\makechapterstyle{ell}{%` at line 3321.

Comment: Well I just downloaded the source from https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/, and it doensn't contain a `memoir.cls` file. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have `memoir.ins`? Run `latex memoir.ins`. But why are you downloading from CTAN? What version of `memoir` are you currently using?

Comment: I figured it out. Just looked for the local version installed by mactex, I thought downloading would be more convenient, as I just wanted to find the macro to redefine, anyway all good.

Comment: So would you be so kind and post it as an answer and accept it? Otherwise it appears under the *unanswered questions*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I ended up modifying it, the `\chs@ell@helper` command needed redefining:

```
%Modify the fancy chapter lines.
\makeatletter
    \usepackage{array}
    \newcolumntype{?}{!{\verticalrule}}
    \renewcommand\chs@ell@helper[1]{%
      \par%
        \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\chapindent}
          \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X?}%|emacs
            \leavevmode\chapnumfont #1\vphantom{1}%
            \hspace*{3.6pt}%
            \color{blue!50!black}\rule[-13.5pt]{0pt}{14.8mm}%
            \\%
            \midrule %\hline%
          \end{tabularx}%
        \end{adjustwidth}%
        \par%
      }%
\makeatother
```